# Google hangouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-hangouts

I am working on an application in asp.net core. I want to add additional functionality for hangout. I want to ask is it possible to create hangout invite links in my asp.net application.
I have a scenario where I want to create hangout link and send the link to the client and book a digital meeting. Any suggestion?

Comment: The Hangouts Chat API is mostly dedicated to manage Bots. However, you could create a Calendar Event (which can generate a Meet link) and retrieve it with the Calendar API.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Can you please give some details of how i can auto create links using Calendar API. We are using this API already in our app. But I am not able to understand how I can do it through it. I would appreciate your help. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can generate a Meet link with the Calendar API. To do so, [create](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) an Event with the following parameter and body:

*conferenceDataVersion*: 1

*Request body:*

```
{
  "end": {
    "date": "2020-07-08"
  },
  "start": {
    "date": "2020-07-07"
  },
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "requestId": "hangoutsMeet"
    }
  }
}
```

The `insert` API call will return, along with other fields, the `hangoutLink` parameter, which is ready to use in-browser:

`"hangoutLink": "https://meet.google.com/id-of-the-meet",`

**References:**

- [Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)
- [Insert event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jescanellas,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I would like to ask I am just using a google celander API and I have not G suite account. This function still  works there and how as I did not found anything regarding "conferenceData" in my api.

Comment: Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data. This is the api used in our application. I am actually quite new to this. I have not developed it I am working in updating the system to enable auto create hangout links

Comment: You have to use the `Google.Apis.Calendar.V3;` library too. Take a look at the [Quickstart for .NET](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet), it has an example to List events. Creating it is just changing the List call to an Insert, but passing the body from my answer as parameter.